# optimize sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a user table in my application.

```
Id  Name    ParentId
1   User1   0
2   User2   1
3   User3   1
4   User4   2
5   User5   2
```

The users have a relationship  like grandparent->parent->child. to fetch the users related to a grand parent I'm using the following query

```
select * from user where ParentId=1 or ParentId in(select id from user where ParentId=1)
```

also these user have multiple roles in my role table and for fetching the count of rules a user having, I'm using `select count(*) from group where userId=1`.

```
Id  Role    UserId
1   Role 1  1
2   Role 2  1
3   Role 3  2
4   Role 4  2
5   Role 5  3
```

I need to fetch these both data in a single query .I'm not good with SQL and I know my first query is not perfect . How can I achieve this.

Comment: `need to fetch these both data in a single query` => How? Can you give sample data form `group` table as well and show your expected output based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is just need to be joined with your roles table.

```
SELECT u.id, count(r.id) no_of_roles
FROM user u left join roles r
on u.id = r.userid
WHERE u.ParentId=1
OR u.ParentId  IN
  (SELECT id FROM t WHERE ParentId=1
  )
group by u.id;
```